# what's the different between SqlMapClient and SqlMapSeesion in ibatis?

Tags: ibatis, spring-orm

When I read ibatis-sqlmap-2.3.4,I find They both implements SqlMapExecutor.

SqlMapClientImpl do insert with localSqlMapSession which provide thread safe.

But in spring2.5.6, the execute method of SqlMapClientTemplate use SqlMapClientImpl like this:

```
  SqlMapSession session = this.sqlMapClient.openSession();
  ...
  return action.doInSqlMapClient(session);
```

The openSession method return a new SqlMapSessionImpl each time.

My questions are:

Why SqlMapClientTemplate  use sqlMapSeesion instead of sqlMapClient ?

Why localSqlMapSession of sqlMapClient is unused in SqlMapClientTemplate ? use like this:

```
 return action.doInSqlMapClient(this.sqlMapClient);
```

what's the different between SqlMapClient and SqlMapSeesion ?

Answer (score 3):

for your first question, spring-orm explain in the comment:

```
// We always need to use a SqlMapSession, as we need to pass a Spring-managed
// Connection (potentially transactional) in. This shouldn't be necessary if
// we run against a TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy underneath, but unfortunately
// we still need it to make iBATIS batch execution work properly: If iBATIS
// doesn't recognize an existing transaction, it automatically executes the
// batch for every single statement...
```

the answer to difference between ibatis' SqlMapClient and SqlMapSession can be found in interface SqlMapClient's comments:

```
/**
* Returns a single threaded SqlMapSession implementation for use by
* one user.  Remember though, that SqlMapClient itself is a thread safe SqlMapSession
* implementation, so you can also just work directly with it.  If you do get a session
* explicitly using this method <b>be sure to close it!</b>  You can close a session using
* the sqlMapSession.close() method.
* <p/>
*
* @return An SqlMapSession instance.
*/
public SqlMapSession openSession();
```